# Posting a variable derived from localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my HTML booking form table I have:

```
    <TR><TD align=right>Leader: </TD><TD id="leader" name="leader"></TD></TR>
```

and two input fields "messagein" and "namein", and populate the form from another page using:

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById("leader").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("leader");
    </script>
```

This works fine and shows the name of leader on the form. The form gets posted by:

```
    <FORM name="BOOKING" METHOD="post" ACTION="booking.php" target="_isblank">
```

In booking.php on my web provider's page I have:

```
    <?php
    $message .= "Leader: " . $_POST["leader"] . "\n";
    $message .= "NAME: " . $_POST["namein"] . "\n";
    $message .= "Message: " . $_POST["messagein"] . "\n";
    $subject = "MSR booking " . $_POST["namein"] . " to " . $_POST["leader"];
    $sent = mail([email address], $subject, $message);
    ?>
```

My problem is that the two input fields "messagein" and "namein" are fine, but the "leader" is blank.
How can I post the "leader", without using jscript?

Comment: You need to have an `input` field with `name="leader"`, for it to be sent with the form. Right now, you're not adding it to the form

Comment: Would be useful to see the whole form from `<form>` to `</form>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add input field in td

```
    <TR><TD align=right>Leader: </TD><TD><input type="text" id="leader" name="leader"></TD></TR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `input` field with `name="leader"`, for it to be sent with the form. If you don't want to show an input to the user, you can make it hidden and still show the value as text:

```html
<!--                 remove name="leader" here         -->
<TR><TD align=right>Leader: </TD><TD id="leader"></TD></TR>
```

and insert a hidden input with that name:

```js
var v = localStorage.getItem("leader");
document.getElementById("leader").innerHTML = v
                              + '<input type="hidden" name="leader" value="' + v + '">';
```

Another, better way, would be to already have that hidden input in your HTML, somewhere else in the form, and do :

```
var v = localStorage.getItem("leader");
document.getElementById("leader").innerHTML = v;
document.querySelector('input[name="leader"]').value = v;
```

... but I don't know the structure of your HTML

Comment: Alas, no luck. I got your variable v as I need to put the data in two places, the form display and the Input posting. The form display works as before, but whatever I do I always get v in the Input, not its value. I don't understand the reasoning behind your value="' + v + '", but anyway I couldn't get it to work. For faultfinding I made the input box visible, but I could never get the value of v to appear in the box. I tried giving the Input tag a name and used getElementById to but the value of v into it, like it did for the TD tag on the form, but to no avail.

Comment: @DaveW Weird, could you show your code? At least your form's HTML (from `<form>` to `</form>`) and the JS you now have. In a [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), or a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), or something like that

Comment: I'm glad to say I've won through! One thing I had to do was remove the spaces round the equal signs in the javascript getting from localstorage and stuffing to elements.

Comment: (My enter key just ended my typing instead of adding a new line)
Ah, shift+enter works
.
Instead of displaying the leader on my form by stuffing it into the TD tag, I added an input form to the cell and stuffed that, The id is used for stuffing and the name is used for posting:
<TD><input type="text" id="leader3" name="leader3" style="border:0; font-
size:100%"></TD>

The input now has the dual purpose of displaying and posting. I dispensed with variable v and wrote the getting and stuffing on one line like the other elements:

I needed 55 attempts to get a satisfactory result!

Comment: The shift+enters changed my comment box, but have not appeared in the posting. In future I will have to make each paragraph a separate posting.